# If condition and Mutate to create columns

Tags: r, if-statement, group-by, dplyr

I am using this code , though I am not getting desired output .

**Any error here ?**

```
{
   {if(rd_3$results.cluster=='Visitor' | rd_3$results.cluster=='Employee')
   rd_3<- as.data.frame(rd_3 %>% group_by(device_id,hotel,start_date) %>% mutate(visit_no.=cumsum(c(T,diff.Date(start_date) > 0))))}
{if(rd_3$results.cluster=='Guest') rd_3<- as.data.frame(rd_3 %>%
group_by(device_id,hotel) %>% mutate(visit_no.=cumsum(c(T,diff.Date(start_date) > 1))))}}
```

Comment: Perhaps try `if("Visitor" %in% rd_3$results.cluster)` and similarly for other conditions

Comment: Please edit your question and properly format your code using the editing tools. At the moment, this is a mess.